# Can you cast True Strike and upon the next turn cast a touch spell through a familar for advantage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, familiars, touch-attacks, cantrips

I am rather curious about the interactions between Find Familiar and True Strike in the case of touch spells in D&D 5e. My understanding is that the touch spell can be delivered by a familiar, but does that alter the rules of True Strike providing advantage?

So I ask!

Can you cast True Strike and upon the next turn cast a touch spell through a familar for advantage?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. The [rules-as-written] tag is for questions involving a strict literalist interpretation of the rules even when it leads to absurd interpretations, not for regular rules questions, so I've removed the tag.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## You cannot

True Strike: (emphasis mine)

> Your magic grants **you** a brief insight into the target’s defenses. On
>   your next turn, **you** gain advantage on **your** first attack roll against
>   the target, provided that this spell hasn’t ended.

Find Familiar: (emphasis mine)

> Finally, when you cast a spell with a range of touch, your familiar
>   can deliver the spell **as if it had cast the spell**. Your familiar must
>   be within 100 feet of you, and it must use its reaction to deliver the
>   spell when you cast it. If the spell requires an attack roll, you use
>   your attack modifier for the roll.

Unfortunately, the familiar delivers the spell, and true strike indicates that it only takes effect if you had cast the spell.